# Issue linking containers in Docker using Docker-compose

Tags: java, postgresql, docker, spring-boot, docker-compose

I'm using Docker to get my micro services architecture ready.
I'm facing some problem trying to link one container with another using docker-compose.

Basically I have a container for a postgressql image, and the a java micro service developed with spring boot that should connect to the database container.

So I'm setting a link in docker-compose.yml and referencing the db container ip as 'db' using :

`- "JAVA_OPTS=-Dpostgres.host=db"`

However I'm getting the following error starting the microservice with docker:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'postgress.host' in value "jdbc:postgresql://${postgress.host}:5432/docker"

So basically this placeholder cannot be resolved, but normally docker-composed should take care of setting this system variable to point to the db container IP address right?

What I'm doing wrong?

Below the files involved:

docker-compose.yml:

```
    version: "2"
services:
  microservices:
      build: ./microservices
      container_name: microservices
      links:
        - db
        - consul
      environment:
        - "JAVA_OPTS=-Dpostgres.host=db"
  consul:
      image: consul
      container_name: consul
      ports:
                - "8500:8500"
  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: local-postgres9.6
    ports:
          - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: docker
      POSTGRES_USER: docker
```

application.yml of the microservice:

```
    server:
  port: 8081

project:
  jdbc:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://${postgres.host}:5432/docker
    driver: org.postgresql.Driver
    username: docker
    password: docker
```

Comment: It's not resolving the placeholder, this is the java code not picking up your option, not the DNS resolution that docker and docker-compose provide.

Comment: But this is the only way to link containers each other right? I mean, the one not doing his job here is docker-compose, not setting the system variable to the right value so that the placeholder can be resolved. Any other way to do what I need?

Comment: Do you know the environment variable is not defined? Try a `docker exec -i $container_id env` on your "microservices" container id. If the environment variable is getting defined, then the issue is that java is not using it.

Answer (score 0):

Try `${db.host}`, according to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links):

> Containers for the linked service will be reachable at a hostname
>   identical to the alias, or the service name if no alias was specified.

Comment: No luck but thanks, I just discovered that JAVA_OPTS might work only when using a tomcat image. In my case I'm deploying a springboot fat jar with a embedded tomcat, so maybe that's the reason the system variable is  not getting set